# Changing text depending on date

Tags: javascript

I am an absolute beginner in Javascript writing. I would like to create a code that would display a text in a given date interval (e.g. 2022.10.23-2022.11.25), but not in any other date interval. Try as I might with this code, it fails. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<label id="lblGreetings"></label>  <script> var myDate = new Date(); var hrs = myDate.getHours(); var greet;

if ((myDate = 'October 24, 2022')) greet = 'Good Morning';    document.getElementById('lblGreetings').innerHTML = '<b>' + greet + '</b> and welcome to Encodedna.com!'; </script>
```

Comment: "it fails" - what does that mean? Why do you try to set `myDate` to a string (through `myDate = ...`) after initializing it as a Date object?

Comment: Hi. You can check `Date.now()` if its value is between the date range's `getTime()` values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how familiar you are to Object Oriented Programming. If you're not, it would be beneficial to familiarize yourself with it.

`new Date()` is instantiation of the [`Date` class in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), and it's an object with its own properties and methods. Since it is an object, you cannot compare it to a date string (such as "October 24, 2022").

You can, on the other hand, compare it with another `Date` object, so a good approach would be to get the current date every time your page loads, and compare it with the start and end dates of your interval, and then decide to whether or not to display the text.

```
const startDate = new Date("October 23, 2022");
const endDate = new Date("November 25, 2022");
const today = new Date();

// The below is called a ternary operator. 
// If you're not familiar with it, don't be intimated. It's a cool one.
const greet = (today > startDate && today < endDate) ? "Good Morning!" : "";

document.getElementById('lblGreetings').innerHTML = '<b>' + greet + '</b> and welcome to Encodedna.com!';
```

This is not necessarily how you'd write JavaScript as you get more experienced, but this is a good place to begin with.

Comment: This works great. Is it possible to format this text? "Good Morning!" E.g. different background, padding, etc. I need this because if I style the div, it will show up with padding and red background outside of the specified days.

Comment: It is possible, but the *how* depends a lot on what you have in mind and how your HTML is structured. If you want to style just the `greet` text, you could add a class to the `<b>` wrapper that you're putting around it, and use the class to style the element.